# Error en $sentencia al insertar usuarios en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Al intentar hacer la sentencia para pasarla a la base de datos me salen los siguientes errores.

[image: Error 1]

Codigo repositoriousuario:

```
public static function insertar_usuario($conexion, $usuario){
        $usuario_insertado = false;

        if (isset($conexion)){
            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, email, password, fecha_registro, activo) 
                /*AQUI PONEMOS ALIAS*/VALUES(:nombre, :email, :password, NOW(), 0)";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);

                $sentencia -> bindParam(':nombre', $usuario -> obtener_nombre(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $usuario -> obtener_email(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':password', $usuario -> obtener_password(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $sentencia -> execute();
                $usuario_insertado = $sentencia -> fetch();
            }catch (PDOException $ex){
                print 'ERROR'. $ex->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $usuario_insertado;
    }
```

No se como arreglarlo.

Y además me aparece este siguiente error:

[image: Error 2]

Codigo config:

```
define('NOMBRE_SERVIDOR', 'localhost');
define('NOMBRE_USUARIO', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('NOMBRE_BD', 'blog');
```

Conexion :

```
class Conexion{
        private static $conexion;

        public static function abrir_conexion(){
            if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
                try{
                   include "config.inc.php";

                  
                    self::$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.NOMBRE_SERVIDOR.'; dbname='.NOMBRE_BD.'; port=3307; charset=utf8', NOMBRE_USUARIO, PASSWORD);
                    self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    // Si ponemos lo siguiente comentado no funciona
                    //self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER utf8");
                }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    print "<db>"."ERROR: " . $ex -> getMessage() . "<br>";
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        public static function cerrar_conexion(){
            if (isset(self::$conexion)){
                self::$conexion = null;
            }
        }

        // Para usar referencia a conexion fuera de esta clase ya que es privada
        public static function obtener_conexion(){
            return self::$conexion;
        }
    }
```

Este creia q cambiandolo a define en vez de variables se arreglaria, pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es para PHP en general: cuando aparezca el mensaje, [only values should be passed by reference](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+only+variables+should+be+passed+by+reference), significa que la instrucción en cuestión no puede ejecutar internamente el llamado a una función o un método. 
En otras palabras: primero debes asignarle el valor de retorno a una variable y luego meterla en la instrucción. Entonces:

```
$nombre = $usuario->obtener_nombre();
$sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// ... y así con las demás instrucciones
```

Y el segundo error es porque el archivo config está siendo importado desde otro archivo que es llamado desde `conexión`, o sea múltiples veces. Para resolver - a lo rápido - ese problema, usa `include_once 'config.inc.php'` o `require_once 'config.inc.php';`

Comment: Perfecto solucionado, tenia abierta conexion en ese archivo, y luego dentro de un include_once otra conexion.